# Where do I put response.success()?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am new to Parse and I am just creating my first Cloud Code, where I am running into an issue where a `Parse.Query` does not finish, because obviously `response.success()` will be called too early.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("items",function(request,response){
    hasPictures = calc(request);
    request.object.set("hasPictures",hasPictures);

    response.success();
});

function calc(request){
    var hasPictures = false;
    var userPictureCount = getPictureCountForUser(request.object.get("uniqueIdentifier"));

    // something else is being calculated here. removed it so simplify

    if(userPictureCount > 0)
    hasPictures = true;

    return hasPictures;
}

var getPictureCountForUser = function(uniqueIdentifier){

    var query = new Parse.Query("items");
    if(Parse.User.current()){   
        a.equalTo("userId", Parse.User.current().id);
    }else{
        query.equalTo("uniqueIdentifier", uniqueIdentifier);
    }

    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            //console.log(results.length + ' pictures found!');
            console.log(results);
            // return results.length; 
            response.success(results);        
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("Query failed. Error = " + error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

I know that I somehow have to deal with Promises. But I don't know how to achieve it.

The `Parse.Query` in `getPictureCountForUser()` never really finds something, because of the `response.success()` being in the wrong place. Where do I have to put it, especially with that `calc()` in between?

So that each function will wait for the other one to finish before sending `response.success()` too soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use promises but for your particular case, if you wan't to use promises you could use only a callback, no more, something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("items",function(request,response){
    hasPictures = calc(request, function(hasPictures) {
        // i don't know your logic, you could do a response.success of failure, what do you need
        request.object.set("hasPictures",hasPictures);

        response.success();
    });
});

function calc(request, callback){
    var hasPictures = false;
    getPictureCountForUser(request.object.get("uniqueIdentifier"), function(userPictureCount) {
    if(userPictureCount > 0)
        hasPictures = true;

    callback(hasPictures);
    });
};

var getPictureCountForUser = function(uniqueIdentifier, callback){
    var query = new Parse.Query("items");
    if(Parse.User.current()){   
        a.equalTo("userId", Parse.User.current().id);
    }else{
        query.equalTo("uniqueIdentifier", uniqueIdentifier);
    }

    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            callback(results.length);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            callback(-1);
            //response.error("Query failed. Error = " + error.message);
        }
    });
};
```